# Postgresql SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: Ö

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

This question was asked many times, but no solution worked for me, I have this piece of code:

```
Changes::$change['text'] = $data->employee->emp_first_name . ", " . $data->employee->emp_last_name . " in Woche " .  $data->employee->week . " gelöscht <br>";
Changes::$change['user'] = $data->user->name;
$date = date_create();
$changeLogSql = utf8_encode("INSERT INTO change_log (date, name, change, affected_table) VALUES (now(), '". Changes::$change['user'] ."', '". Changes::$change['text'] ."', '" . Changes::$change['table'] . "')");
$fetched[0]['debug'] = $changeLogSql;
$result = $pdo->query($changeLogSql);
```

Without the `utf8_encode` I get sometimes the error:

`Postgresql SQLSTATE[22021]: Character not in repertoire: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8":`

In this `Insert` the problem is the `ö` in `gelöscht`. This could I fix by my own but some name´s also contain the character ö and lead to the same byte sequence error.

In my test enviroment it works fine, just on the production side the error occurs. Both using potsgresql 9.6.

Any idea how I can get it working without `utf8_encode`? With it, it looks like "Ã¶t" in my database.

[image]

A small addition in the same php file I also insert the same names without any problem in different tables (without encode). The problem only occurs in this statement. All name fields are defined as text or varchar.

Comment: If the data in your application are not in UTF-8, you can set the `client_encoding` of the PostgreSQL connection appropriately, then PostgreSQL will automatically convert the data.